# Directional Hover: Overlay doesn't fully leave container

Tags: jquery, plugins, hover, jquery-animate, overlay

I am using this plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Mouse-Direction-aware-jQuery-Hover-Effect-Plugin-Directional-Hover.html

I got it working however when the mouse leaves the photo, the overlay position doesn't leave completely. I'm assuming the calculations in the plugin is wrong or my css has some dimension issues. Can anyone help me out?

You can view my work here: https://jsfiddle.net/7mw2y4m7/

And here is the plugin js that I'm using

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.directionalHover = function(options) {
    // Extend default plugin options
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.directionalHover.defaults, options);

    // Create bit flags
    var FLAG_T = 1, // top
        FLAG_R = 2, // right
        FLAG_B = 4, // bottom
        FLAG_L = 8; // left

    // Create bit masks
    var tlMask = FLAG_T | FLAG_L,
        trMask = FLAG_T | FLAG_R,
        blMask = FLAG_B | FLAG_L,
        brMask = FLAG_B | FLAG_R;

    function slideOverlay(overlay, direction, px, py, ew, eh, ex, ey) {
        var cornerFlags = 0; // top|right|bottom|left

        if (py - ey <= eh / 2) cornerFlags ^= FLAG_T;
        if (px - ex >= ew / 2) cornerFlags ^= FLAG_R;
        if (py - ey >  eh / 2) cornerFlags ^= FLAG_B;
        if (px - ex <  ew / 2) cornerFlags ^= FLAG_L;

        findSide(cornerFlags, overlay, direction, px-ex, py-ey, ew/2, eh/2);
    }

    function findSide(flags, overlay, direction, x, y, w, h) {
        if (testMask(flags, tlMask)) {
            testTopLeftToBottomRight(x, y, w, h) ? setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, 0, -w*2) : setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, -h*2, 0);
        }
        else if (testMask(flags, trMask)) {
            testBottomRightToTopLeft(x, y, w, h) ? setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, -h*2, 0) : setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, 0, w*2);
        }
        else if (testMask(flags, blMask)) {
            testBottomRightToTopLeft(x, y, w, h) ? setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, 0, -w*2) : setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, h*2, 0);
        }
        else if (testMask(flags, brMask)) {
            testTopLeftToBottomRight(x, y, w, h) ? setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, h*2, 0) : setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, 0, w*2);
        }
    }

    function testMask(flags, mask) {
        return (flags & mask) === mask;
    }

    function testTopLeftToBottomRight(x, y, w, h) {
        return (h * x - w * y) < 0;
    }

    function testBottomRightToTopLeft(x, y, w, h) {
        return (w * (y-h) + h * x - w * h) < 0;
    }

    function setOverlayPosition(overlay, direction, top, left) {
        if (direction === 'in') {
            overlay.animate({
                top: top,
                left: left
            }, 0, function() {
                overlay.stop().animate({
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                }, opts.speed, opts.easing);
            });
        }
        else if (direction === 'out') {
            overlay.animate({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }, 0, function() {
                overlay.stop().animate({
                    top: top,
                    left: left
                }, opts.speed, opts.easing);
            });
        }
    }

    this.css({
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });

    this.find('.' + opts.overlay).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '-100%'
    });

    return this.each(function() {
        var container = $(this);

        container.hover(function(e) {
            slideOverlay(
                container.find('.' + opts.overlay),
                'in',
                e.pageX,
                e.pageY,
                container.width(),
                container.height(),
                Math.floor(container.offset().left),
                container.offset().top
            );
        }, function(e) {
            slideOverlay(
                container.find('.' + opts.overlay),
                'out',
                e.pageX,
                e.pageY,
                container.width(),
                container.height(),
                Math.floor(container.offset().left),
                container.offset().top
            );
        });
    });
};

// Plugin default options
$.fn.directionalHover.defaults = {
    overlay: "dh-overlay",
    easing: "swing",
    speed: 400
};

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: This is because of the `padding: 8px` rule of the container. You can set the rule for overlay instead of the container. Here is a updated fiddle that also uses `box-sizing: border-box;` rule. https://jsfiddle.net/7mw2y4m7/1/

Comment: You are very welcome!